# How to convert nested json in csv with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a nested json file (100k rows), which looks like this:

```
{"UniqueId":"4224f3c9-323c-e911-a820-a7f2c9e35195","TransactionDateUTC":"2019-03-01 15:00:52.627 UTC","Itinerary":"MUC-CPH-ARN-MUC","OriginAirportCode":"MUC","DestinationAirportCode":"CPH","OneWayOrReturn":"Return","Segment":[{"DepartureAirportCode":"MUC","ArrivalAirportCode":"CPH","SegmentNumber":"1","LegNumber":"1","NumberOfPassengers":"1"},{"DepartureAirportCode":"ARN","ArrivalAirportCode":"MUC","SegmentNumber":"2","LegNumber":"1","NumberOfPassengers":"1"}]}
```

I am trying to create a csv, so that it can easily be loaded in a rdbms. I am trying to use json_normalize() in pandas but even before I get there I am getting below error.

```py
with open('transactions.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

`JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 466)`

Comment: Question: does your data file contain 100k rows, each with a separate valid JSON record, or it is all one very long JSON structure in there?

Comment: each with separate valid json record. it looks like a single line for each row when opened in excel

Comment: And do all the records have exactly the structure shown in your example here? There's going to be a challenge converting this nested structure into a flat CSV, you have to decide what you want to do with the `"Segment"` list - does it go into one cell? Does each of its element go into its own cell? What do you want to do the with key-value pairs inside each of its elements?

Comment: each segment should go to its own cell.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a more complete solution.

Comment: If any answer below helped solve your problem, please consider upvoting and/or accepting them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If your problem originates in reading the json file itself, then i would just use:

```
json.loads()
```

and then use

```
pd.read_csv()
```

If your problem originates in the conversion from your json dict to dataframe you can use this:

```
test = {"UniqueId":"4224f3c9-323c-e911-a820-a7f2c9e35195","TransactionDateUTC":"2019-03-01 15:00:52.627 UTC","Itinerary":"MUC-CPH-ARN-MUC","OriginAirportCode":"MUC","DestinationAirportCode":"CPH","OneWayOrReturn":"Return","Segment":[{"DepartureAirportCode":"MUC","ArrivalAirportCode":"CPH","SegmentNumber":"1","LegNumber":"1","NumberOfPassengers":"1"},{"DepartureAirportCode":"ARN","ArrivalAirportCode":"MUC","SegmentNumber":"2","LegNumber":"1","NumberOfPassengers":"1"}]}

import json
import pandas

# convert json to string and read
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(test), convert_axes=True)

# 'unpack' the dict as series and merge them with original df
df = pd.concat([df, df.Segment.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

# remove dict
df.drop('Segment', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

That would be my approach but there might be more convenient approaches.

Comment: Hi, the problem originates in the conversion from your json dict to dataframe. Your solution works for a single line, but I have a file with 100k lines similar to the line that I showed. It fails while reading those lines.

Comment: Then you should follow the approach from @joanis by looping over the single rows to read them.

Answer (score 0):

### Step one: loop over a file of records

Since your file has one JSON record per line, you need to loop over all the records in your file, which you can do like this:

```
with open('transactions.json', encoding="utf8") as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data = json.loads(line) 
        # or
        df = pd.read_json(line, convert_axes=True)
        # do something with data or df
```

### Step two: write the CSV file

Now, you can combine this with a `csv.writer` to convert the file into a CSV file.

```
with open('transactions.csv', "w", encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    #Loop for each record, somehow:
        #row = build list with row contents
        writer.writerow(row)
```

### Putting it all together

I'll read the first record once to get the keys to display and output them as a CSV header, and then I'll read the whole file and convert it one record at a time:

```
import copy
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

# Read the first JSON record to get the keys that we'll use as headers for the CSV file
with open('transactions.json', encoding="utf8") as data_file:
    keys = list(json.loads(next(data_file)).keys())

# Our CSV headers are going to be the keys from the first row, except for
# segments, which we'll replace (arbitrarily) by three numbered segment column
# headings.
keys.pop()
base_keys = copy.copy(keys)
keys.extend(["Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3"])

with open('transactions.csv', "w", encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(keys)  # Write the CSV headers

    with open('transactions.json', encoding="utf8") as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            data = json.loads(line)
            row = [data[k] for k in base_keys] + data["Segment"]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The resulting CSV file will still have a JSON record in each Segment*i* column. If you want to format each segment differently, you could define a `format_segment(segment)` function and replace `data["Segment"]` by this list comprehension: `[format_segment(segment) for segment in data["Segment"]]`